# Same php markup of two link's "href" attribute, is outputting two different html

Tags: php, url

The php template -

```
"home-pg-feed-video" => 
    "<div class=\"row home-pg-feed-item pl0 pr0 ml0 mr0\" data-type=\"video\">" .
        "<div class=\"col-lg-4 col-xs-4 pl0\">" .
            "<a href=\"/clinical-dialogue.php?v={{ url }}\"><img src=\"{{ thumb-sm }}\" alt=\"img\"/></a>" .
        "</div>" .
        "<div class=\"col-lg-8 col-xs-8 pr0 \">" .
            "<h4 class=\"mb5\">{{ title }}</h4>" .
            "<a href=\"/clinical-dialogue.php?v={{ url }}\" class=\"watch-link\">Watch the video</a>" .
            "<p>{{ summary }}</p>" .
        "</div>" .
    "</div>"
```

The link with "img" tag inside outputs correctly -

```
<a href="/clinical-dialogue.php?v=Dirk_Arnold_Patient_Selection_3rd_Line_&amp;_Sequencing_Final_Branded-video.php"><img src="images/vid_thumbs/sm/Dirk_Arnold_Branded.png" alt="img"></a>
```

But the second link of "watch video" outputs -

```
<a href="/clinical-dialogue.php?v={{ url }}" class="watch-link">Watch the video</a>
```

The markup where I am using the template

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-feed">
                    <h3 class="feed-name mt0">Featured Clinical Dialogue</h3>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < count($featureData); $i++){
                            $item = $featureData[$i];
                            if($item["type"] === "video"){
                                $template = $templates["home-pg-feed-video"];
                                $html = $template;

                                foreach($item as $key => $value){
                                    if($key == "topics") {
                                            $value = implode(", ", $value);
                                        }   
                                        $html = preg_replace("/{{ " . $key . " }}/", $value, $html, 1);
                                }
                                echo $html;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "1" in your `preg_replace` line which limits the number of matches (i.e. "url") to just 1. Use '-1' to not have a limit.

So

```
$html = preg_replace("/{{ " . $key . " }}/", $value, $html, -1);
```

Or

```
$html = preg_replace("/{{ " . $key . " }}/", $value, $html);
```

However in your case there is no need for regex. Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as it is faster:

```
$html = str_replace("{{ " . $key . " }}", $value, $html);
```

Comment: Did not change anything.  @yashua

Comment: Weird. I just ran your template through the preg_replace with -1 and it worked.

Comment: Wierd indeed.
What am I missing ...  @yashua

Comment: "<p>{{ summary }}</p>" . Which comes after the link outputs correctly, but the link before the does not.  @yashua

Comment: With "1" as the limit I would expect all your replacement to work except for the second "url". Removing the "1" (or using -1) should effectively cause all {{ url }} to change. Try removing the first one from the template to see if the second one works and also to make sure there are no weird invisible characters in the {{ url }} expression try copying and pasting the first {{ url }} to the second one.

Comment: Removing the first link works, now its outputting the second link correctly.  @yashua

Comment: To confirm - I've edited my question. You do have the `preg_replace` statement fixed as indicated in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have copied and tried your provided lines of code exactly . @Yashua

Comment: I'm rather baffled. Try `str_replace` instead.

Comment: same result  @yashua.
Thank you very for you response.

Comment: Does this gist work for you? https://gist.github.com/cyberwombat/49afe346b11fc290cbd328aad8a4c6c2

Comment: I wrapped the whole code in one a tag, and adjusted styles.  @Yashua

Comment: I will let you know, shortly.  @yashua